# Access Gantt Chart

Tags: ms-access, database-projects

I designed and maintained a database used to track my organizations projects. Access frontend with a SQL backend. I have a table for all the scheduling events. Task, Start, Finish, duration etc. Really basic. I am looking to create a form or report that displays a Gantt chart. At the same time I'd also like to create what we call a Bird on Wire Chart. Not sure it that is a term unique to my group. It is a line divided up in months with triangles associated with events and dates. Project managers use power point to move the triangles around to show major milestones for their project. I'd like to automate this somehow using the data from the schedule table. 
First is it possible to do these things? and second and example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There are a [number of sql report generators that can produce GANTT charts](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sql%20report%20builder%20gantt%20chart). Might be easier than rolling your own!